# Effective use of FREETEXTTABLE and CONTAINSTABLE for phone number search

Tags: sql-server

Let's assume that I have several columns for phone numbers - home, work, mobile, etc. These columns are free text, so numbers can be entered in various formats like '0044123456789', '+44 0123 4567 789', '123-456-789', and so on. The search field is also free text, so the query can vary. I have created a FULLTEXT INDEX on the columns of interest to me, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to effectively use FREETEXTTABLE or CONTAINSTABLE. For instance, if the number is '123-456-789' and I search for '123456-789', I get results. However, when I search for '123456789', I get nothing.

While normalizing inputs would be ideal, I don't own the data (though I can create view with computed columns if needed). Maybe I'm on the wrong path altogether? Thank you.

```
SELECT
     fts.RANK
    ,p.Mobile
    ,p.Home
    ,p.Work
    ,...
FROM DataTbl as p
JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(DataTbl, *, @SearchPhrase) AS fts ON p.Id=fts.KEY
ORDER BY fts.RANK DESC
```

Comment: What level of control do you have over the database?...i.e. what objects can you create? Are you able to manipulate the source tables? Normalizing the data would be ideal, and is rather easy to do for phone numbers, without even having to change the application. That's how I currently I handle them to be consistent. I try to avoid the Full Text Search feature if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: I can create new db objects, but this particular table is not mine to change.